# Is Poisson formula valid for the weak solution of Laplacian?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In the book "Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE", here is a theorem as follows

> Theorem(Harnack's inequality). Assume $ u\in H^1(B_1) $ is a non-negative, is the weak solution for the laplace equation $ \Delta{u}=0\text{ in }B_1 $ where $ B_1 $ is the ball with center $ 0 $ and radius $ 1 $. Then the infimum and the supermum of $ u $ are comparable in $ B_{1/2} $. That is, there exists $ C $ depending only on $ n $, such that
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \sup_{B_{1/2}}u\leq C\inf_{B_{1/2}}u.
> \end{eqnarray}

The proof of this theorem in this book is by using Poisson kernel representation as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
u(x)=C_n\int_{\partial B_{1}}\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}u(y)dS(y),(*)
\end{eqnarray}
where $ C_n $ is a constant depending only on $ n $. I know that the proof of the final result is trivial by this representation formula. However I doubt the correctness of this Poisson kernel representation. By using the Weyl Lemma, I see that $ u\in C^{\infty}(B_1) $, but on $ \partial B_1 $, I cannot get that $ u(x)|_{\partial B_1} $ is continuous. Therefore, my question is the formula (*) correct for the weak solution $ u $ and how to derive this formula? Moreover, I know that if we use the Poisson integration on $ \partial B_{3/4} $, we can also have the Harnack inequality, but I still want to know if we can use the Poisson integration on $ \partial B_{1} $

Comment: Idea: Consider the Poisson formula instead on $\partial B_r$ for $r<1$, then use the fact that $u\in H^1(B_1)$ to take the limit as $r\to 1^-$.

Comment: @ Jose27, can you give more details? I have some troubles in dealing with the limits.

Comment: Under [one of my recent answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253182/350803) (to one of your questions, BTW), a commenter added a reference to [Folland's Introduction to PDE](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equ/p2XcDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) (theorem 2.48, page 97), which supposedly shows how Poisson's formula can be used for solutions in $H^1(B_1)$. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz, I still cannot use the references you gave me. Here $ u|_{\partial\Omega}\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) $ and I cannot go on. Can you give me more details?